# how to filter the output of an array produced with a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, file, foreach

For reading all `.txt` files in a directory, i use code blow:

```
// Grab all the files from subscribers dir
$dir = 'subscribers/';
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($file = readdir($dh))!== false){
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // This line strips out . & ..                                     
                $all_subscribers[] = $file;   // put all files in array 
        }
    }           
}
closedir($dh);
asort($all_subscribers);
```

Each txt file has 4 lines and looks like this:

```
id-12345678 // id
Friends // name of category
John // name subscriber
john.smith@gmail.com // email subscriber
```

Output:

```
foreach($all_subscribers as $file) { 
    // open and prepare files
    $all_subscribers_files = 'subscribers/'.$file;          
    // get data out of txt file     
    $lines = file($all_subscribers_files, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // set lines from all files into an array 
    $recipients_category = $lines[1];               
    $recipients_name = $lines[2]; //  name of recipients
    $recipients_email = $lines[3]; //  email of the recipients                  
    //$mail->AddCC($recipients_email, $recipients_name);                            
}
```

When i echo `$recipients_email` it shows me all the email-addresses form all subscribers.

When i echo `$recipients_category`, it shows me all the categories form each subscriber.
I have 5 categories: `Friends, Collegas, Family, Club and Offside`

How can i strip out the emails corresponding to `Offside` category?
So when i `echo $recipients_email;` it should give me all the email-addresses from all categories except from `Offside` category...

Comment: Why aren't you using a database for this?

Comment: It is a simple script and for that reason i want to make it in a flat-file database like .txt files

Comment: Believe me and take this from experience. Text files are a lot of work for doing something as simple as that. A database will help you with this and will make maintaining it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to collect all emails from all categories (except `Offside`) :

```php
$results = [];

foreach ($all_subscribers as $file) {
    $all_subscribers_files = 'subscribers/' . $file;
    $lines                 = file($all_subscribers_files, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    // If category is not Offside
    if ($lines[1] != 'Offside') {
        // Collect email
        $results[] = $lines[3];
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Awesome! Really simple solution but i could not come up with it...

Answer (score 1):

You could filter as you go, or add each file array to one big collection and then filter as you like:

```
<?php
$collection =
[
    ['id-12345678', 'Friends', 'Luke', 'skywalker@example.com'],
    ['id-23456789', 'Enemy', 'Darth', 'vader@example.com']
];

$no_evil = array_filter($collection, function($item) {
    return $item[1] !== 'Enemy';
});

var_export($no_evil);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'id-12345678',
      1 => 'Friends',
      2 => 'Luke',
      3 => 'skywalker@example.com',
    ),
  )
```